# How to load a big numpy array from a text file with Dask?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dask

I have a text file containing data that I read to memory with [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) enforcing a custom `numpy.dtype`. Although the text file is smaller than the available RAM, I often get a `MemoryError` (which I don't understand, but it is not the point of this question). When looking for ways to resolve it, I came across [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/). In the API I found [methods](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html) for data loading but none of them reads from text files, not to mention my need to support converters in `genfromtxt()`.

I see there is a `dask.dataframe.read_csv()` method, but in my case I don't use pandas, but rather plain `numpy.array` with custom dtypes and colum names, as mentioned above. The text file I have is not CSV anyway (thus the abovementioned use of converters in `genfromtxt()`).

Any ideas on how could I handle it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO editors rejected my edit to @mdurant's answer, thus, I post the working code (based on that answer) here:

```
import numpy 
import dask
import dask.array as da
import io

fname = 'data.txt'
# data.txt is:
# 1 2
# 3 4
# 5 6

files = [fname]
_, blocks = dask.bytes.read_bytes(files, delimiter="\n")

my_type = numpy.dtype([
                    ('f1', numpy.float64),
                    ('f2', numpy.float64)
                    ])

native_type = numpy.float
used_type = numpy.float64
# If the below line is uncommented, then creating the dask array will work, but it won't
# be possible to perform any operations on it
# used_type = my_type

# Debug
# print('blocks', blocks)
# print('type(blocks)', type(blocks))
# print('blocks[0]', blocks[0])
# print('type(blocks[0])', type(blocks[0]))

@dask.delayed
def parse(block):
    r = numpy.genfromtxt(io.BytesIO(block[0]))
    print('parse() about to return:\n', r, '\n')
    return r

# Below I added shape, which seems compulsatory, the reason for which I don't understand
arrays = [da.from_delayed(value=parse(block), shape=(3, ), dtype=used_type) for block in blocks]
# da.concat did not not work for me
arr = da.stack(arrays)
# The below will not work if used_type is set to my_type
arr += 1
# Neither the below woudl work, it raises NotImplementedError
# arr['f1'] += 1
arr_np = arr.compute()
print('numpy array incremented by one: \n', arr_np)
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not notified of any edit! Glad you got it working.

Comment: It was not you, it was some "senior" SO users who review edits. They rejected mine. Anyway, I posted this answer in case someone in the future needs it. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the function `dask.bytes.read_bytes` with `delimiter="\n"` to read your file(s) and split them into blocks at line-endings. You get back a set of `dask.delayed` objects, which you can pass to numpy. Unfortunately, numpy wants a file-like, so you must pack the bytes again:

```
import dask
import dask.array as da
_, blocks = dask.bytes.read_bytes(files, delimiter="\n")

@dask.delayed
def parse(block):
    return numpy.genfromtext(io.BytesIO(block), ...)

arrays = [da.from_delayed(parse(block), ...) for block in blocks]
arr = da.stack/concat(arrays)
```

Comment: Thank you, nevertheless when I call `compute()` on arr I get the following error: "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'" as a result of the attempt to pass `io.BytesIO(block)` to `numpy.genfromtxt()`. I think `numpy.getnfromtxt()` only expects a filename and can't work with byte blocks.  Following your concept, I guess I shall split the original file to many files on disk and then call `numpy.genfromtxt()` on each of them, to later concat the resulting arrays, is that correct?

Comment: Ah, i forgot that blocks is a list of lists. Please flatten, and this will work. Genfromtxt works with file-like objects.

Comment: I had noticed the list issue, flattening did not help, but incorrectly I thought it was due to `genfromtxt()`. `print(io.BytesIO(blocks[0]))` yields `# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'` and `print(io.BytesIO(blocks[0][0]))` yields `# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Delayed'`, thus the issue seems related to how the Delayed object is not being trated as BytesIO, which I don't know how to fix again.

Comment: **Within** the parse function, `blocks[0][0]` is a `bytes` object

Comment: Indeed it is (it is not clear to me why). To make it work I also had to add the `shape` argument to the call to `from_delayed()`. I don't get it either, why can't Dask figure the shape on its own, I do not have to a priori know the size of arrays in text files.  Also `stack` worked, but not `concat`.

Comment: In any case it does work only with a native dtype, e.g. `numpy.float64`. In my case, i.e. with a custom dtype, e.g.  `my_type = numpy.dtype([('f1', numpy.float64),  ('f2', numpy.float64)])`
it seems that the array is create, but when I try to access fields by `arr['f1']`, I get:
NotImplementedError: Item assignment with <class 'str'> not supported

Comment: ^ this is a separate issue, please post on dask github as a feature request. Also, please update the answer with the version that worked for you.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is separate. Nevertheless, I included it in my original question. I will post on github, and also upvote and edit yours, as soon as it stops complaining "Suggested edit queue is full". Thank you for your help.